# w3c validator gives me : Error: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen. another question can i nest a block level element inside another one?

Tags: html

**this is the part of the code that the error in and idont know what the fault did i do here ?**

```
<ol>
<p>

    <li> <em> Markup </em>is just a text that has a special meaning also it tellls the browser what the text should look like or how its arranged 
    
</p> it says that this closing hasnt any opening tag

<p>

     <li> elements with no contents in it are called "void elements" or "empty elements" 
    
</p>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add  `</li>` in the end of each `<li>` . Also inside the `<ol>` you do not need a `<p>...</p>`